# Extension of measures on filtered space

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Consider a filtered space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \{ \mathcal{F}_t \}_{t \geq 0})$ and probability measures $\mathbb{P}^t$ on $\mathcal{F}_t$ that satisfy the compatibility condition, i.e. $\mathbb{P}^t (A) = \mathbb{P}^s (A)$ for $t > s$ and $A \in \mathcal{F}_s$.

**Question**: Is it possible to construct a probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ on $\mathcal{F}_{\infty} = \sigma ( \cup_{t \geq 0} \mathcal{F}_t )$ such that $\mathbb{P}(A) = \mathbb{P}^t(A)$ for any $A \in \mathcal{F}_t$?

Answer (score 2):

It is usually convenient to work with canonical spaces (product spaces) with the natural filtration. (In most situations, such a space can be built so that it exhibits the properties one wants to study).

As you may know,

- when the spaces $\{(S_t,\mathscr{F}_t:t\in T\}$  are nice (Borel spaces)
- your family of probabilities $\{\mu_I:I\subset T\}$ have the projective property ($\mu_J(\cdot\times S_{J\setminus I})=\mu_I(\cdot)$, where $(S_J,\sigma{F}_J)=(\prod_{t\in J}S,\bigotimes_{t\in J}\mathscr{F}_t)$ and $I\subset J$

**Kolmogorov** proved that there is a unique probability measure $\mu$ on $(\prod_{t\in T}S_t,\bigotimes_{t\in T}\mathscr{F}_t)$ such that $\mu_J = \mu(\cdot,S_{T\setminus I})$.  The assumption of having nice spaces is to ensured that regular conditional probabilities exists, or allows for use of the Riesz-Markov representation.

---

If the spaces $(S_t,\mathscr{F}_t)$ are not nice necessarily, but $T$ is countable (say $\mathbb{N}$), and

- there is a sequence of stochastic kernels $\mu_n(s_1,\ldots,s_{n-1}|ds_n)$ from $S_1\times\ldots\times S_{n-1}$ to $S_n$ ($\mu_1$ is a probability measure) such that $\{\mu_1\otimes\ldots\otimes\mu_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a projective family (as above)

**Ionescu Tulcea** proved that existence of a unique probability measure $\mu$ in $(\prod_nS_n,\bigotimes_n\mathscr{F}_n)$ though that $\mu(\cdot\prod_{m>n}S_m)=\mu_1\otimes\ldots\otimes\mu_n(\cdot)$

---

In the case of Kolmogorov's extension, once we have the (unique) measure on the total space, to study stochastic processes the filtrations can be modifies to satisfy several types of regularity conditions (continuity, completion, etc).

---

Several graduate books in Probability explain this. **Kallenberg's** book (Foundations of the Theory of Probability) presents both results using a probabilistic construction (randomization). **Leo Breiman's** book (Probability) has a very good presentation of Kolmogorov's extension.

A good presentation of the details on the properties of nice spaces can be found in **Parthasarathy's** book (Proability Measures on Metric Spaces). This is a not trivial rea though, and it is not essential to know all the details (just be aware of the results) to do probability.